# How to automatically update a property inside a js .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a mapped array which renders some buttons. Then a back and next button (outside of the map). When I click next I want it to update the URL route.  It changes component and shows the next button on the screen but does not change the URL route. I am guessing that inside NavLink - I need the 'to' property to update when the next/back buttons are clicked. Any suggestions where to start with this?

```
const debug = require("debug")("components:Letterindex")
const React = require("react")
const { connect } = require("react-redux")
const request = require("superagent")
const { Link, Redirect } = require("react-router")

const NavLink = require("./NavLink.js")

class Letterindex extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.nextButton = this.nextButton.bind(this)
    this.previousButton = this.previousButton.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  nextButton(letter,letters,dispatch){
    const id = letters.findIndex(item =>{
      return item.id ===letter.id
    })
    if(id === (letters.length -1)){
      dispatch({
        type: "RENDER_LETTER",
        payload: letters[0],
      })
    }
    else {
      return (
        dispatch({
          type: "RENDER_LETTER",
          payload: letters[id+1],
        })
      )
    }
  }

  previousButton(letter,letters,dispatch){
    const id = letters.findIndex(item =>{
      return item.id ===letter.id
    })
    if(id === 0){
      dispatch({
        type: "RENDER_LETTER",
        payload: letters[letters.length-1],
      })
    }
    else {
      return (
        dispatch({
          type: "RENDER_LETTER",
          payload: letters[id-1],
        })
       )
     }
   }

  render() {
debug(this.props)
const { dispatch, letters, letter } = this.props
return (
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-sm-12">

      <img id="back" src="../../images/back.gif" alt="back button"
        onClick={()=>
        this.previousButton(letter, letters, dispatch)}
      />
    {
      letters.map((letter) => {

        return (
          <NavLink
            key={letter.id}
            to={`/letterindex/${letter.capital}`}
            activeClassName="active">
            <div
              className="btn-group btn-group-lg btn-group-center wiggle-me"
              role="group"
              aria-label="...">

              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn"
                onClick={() =>
                    dispatch({
                      type: "RENDER_LETTER",
                      payload: letter,
                    })
                }>
              {letter.capital}
              </button>
            </div>
          </NavLink>
        )
      })
    }

    <img id="next" src="../../images/next.gif" alt="next button"
      onClick={()=>
        this.nextButton(letter, letters, dispatch)}
    />
    {this.props.children}

    </div>
  </div>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = connect(state => state)(Letterindex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a router push to the dispatch in each letter function:

```
  this.props.router.push(`/letterindex/${letters[0].capital}`)
```

Full code for the button here:

```
  nextButton(letter,letters,dispatch){
const id = letters.findIndex(item =>{
  return item.id ===letter.id
})
if(id === (letters.length -1)){
  this.props.router.push(`/letterindex/${letters[0].capital}`)
  dispatch({
    type: "RENDER_LETTER",
    payload: letters[0],
  })
}
else {
  this.props.router.push(`/letterindex/${letters[id+1].capital}`)
    dispatch({
      type: "RENDER_LETTER",
      payload: letters[id+1],
    })
}
```

}